# How do I get my read more button to show more text when i click on it (javascript/css/html)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

Below is the code for the homepage of a website I am trying to create. However, I cannot seem to get my "read more" button to show more text upon clicking it. I realize there are a few "READ MORE" buttons, but because I cannot get any of them to work, I am only concerned with the first Read More button that falls under the "Welcome to our Health Care Clinic" section for now.  I have tried to put an onclick button in different divisions within the section class called "starting text" but that has failed me. Whenever I click the Read More button, no text appears. If anyone can help me with my code, you'd be saving me and I would greatly appreciate it!

```html
<html><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/season-change.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>HealthCare</title>

  
     <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pontano+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
     <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans:300,400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
     <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:300,400,500,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     
     
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/owl.theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/owl.transitions.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <section class="navs">
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">
            <span><i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i></span>
            Central United Medical Hospital
           </a>
        </div>
  
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
             <li><a href="doctors.html">Doctors</a></li>
             <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="faq.html">FAQs</a></li>
       <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div><!-- navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- container-fluid -->
   </nav>
  </section>
  <section class="heading-slider">
   <div id="starting-slider" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
 
      <div class="owl-wrapper-outer"><div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 6366px; left: 0px; display: block; -webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease; transition: all 1000ms ease; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1061px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1061px;"><div class="item">
       <div class="slider-1">
        <div class="slider-inner">
         <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="slider-inner-text">
            <h1>We're Professional</h1>
            <p><br>Nicolas Cage Approves</p>
           </div> 
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1061px;"><div class="item">
       <div class="slider-2">
        <div class="slider-inner">
         <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="slider-inner-text">
            <h1>We're Caring</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis illum dignissimos tempore ad, eos sint ullam </p>
           </div> 
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1061px;"><div class="item">
       <div class="slider-3">
        <div class="slider-inner">
         <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="slider-inner-text">
            <h1>We're Responsible</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis illum dignissimos tempore ad, eos sint ullam </p>
           </div> 
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div></div></div></div>
      
      
    
   <div class="owl-controls clickable"><div class="owl-pagination"><div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div><div class="owl-page active"><span class=""></span></div><div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div></div></div></div>
  </section>

  <section class="starting-text">
        <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="welcome">
            <h2 class="welcome-title">Welcome To Our Health Care Clinic</h2>
            <p class="welcome-txt">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
            <button class="welcome-btn">Read More</button> 
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>


  <section id="services">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="headline text-center">
       Why Choose Us
      </h2>
      <p class="sub-headline text-center">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hservice">
       <div class="service-img">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/service1.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="service-description text-center">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Top Qualified Doctors</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae nisi nostrum sunt cum, consequuntur asperiores, impedit voluptate eveniet modi quas omnis.</p>
        <a href="#" class="rm-btn btn btn-primary">
          Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hservice">
       <div class="service-img">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/service2.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="service-description text-center">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Online Q &amp; A</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio nulla necessitatibus adipisci consequatur explicabo provident officiis fugit. Nihil dolorem officiis.</p>
        <a href="#" class="rm-btn btn btn-primary">
          Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hservice">
       <div class="service-img">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/service3.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="service-description text-center">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Symptom Check</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias ipsum natus, odio quae! Ratione tempora accusantium explicabo tenetur, porro numquam.</p>
        <a href="#" class="rm-btn btn btn-primary">
          Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hservice">
       <div class="service-img">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/service4.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="service-description text-center">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Competitive Pricing</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias ipsum natus, odio quae! Ratione tempora accusantium explicabo tenetur, porro numquam.</p>
        <a href="#" class="rm-btn btn btn-primary">
          Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hservice">
       <div class="service-img">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/service5.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="service-description text-center">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Medical Counseling</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae nisi nostrum sunt cum, consequuntur asperiores, impedit voluptate eveniet modi quas omnis.</p>
        <a href="#" class="rm-btn btn btn-primary">
          Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hservice">
       <div class="service-img">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/service6.jpg" alt="">
       </div>
       <div class="service-description text-center">
        <h4 class="service-heading">Caring Staff</h4>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio nulla necessitatibus adipisci consequatur explicabo provident officiis fugit. Nihil dolorem officiis.</p>
        <a href="#" class="rm-btn btn btn-primary">
          Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></a>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>






  <section id="testimonial" class="text-center">
   <div class="testimonial-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row client-content text-center">
         <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="row">
        <h1>Testimonial</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="row">
        <div class="sub-headline">
         <p>What Our Patients Say About Us</p>
        </div>
       </div>
          
       <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    

         <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
           <div class="item active left">
              <div id="client-speech">
          <div class="item">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
             <p class="client-comment text-center">
              When you form a team, why do you try to form a team? Because teamwork builds trust and trust builds speed.
             </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
             <img class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/client3.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div> 
           </div>
           <div class="row text-center">
            <p class="client-name text-center">Julia Doe</p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
           </div>
          <div class="item next left">
            <div id="client-speech">
          <div class="item">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
             <p class="client-comment text-center">
              When you form a team, why do you try to form a team? Because teamwork builds trust and trust builds speed.
             </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
             <img class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/client1.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div> 
           </div>
           <div class="row text-center">
            <p class="client-name text-center">John Doe</p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
           </div>
           <div class="item">
              <div id="client-speech">
          <div class="item">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
             <p class="client-comment text-center">
              When you form a team, why do you try to form a team? Because teamwork builds trust and trust builds speed.
             </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
             <i class="fa fa-quote-right"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
             <img class="img-circle img-responsive center-block" src="assets/img/client4.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div> 
           </div>
           <div class="row text-center">
            <p class="client-name text-center">Jane Doe</p>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
           </div>
         </div>

          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="appointment">
       
                       <div class="header text-center">
                           <h2>Make an Appointment</h2>
                           <a href="#" class="number">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i>
          1-800-123-4567
                           </a>
                           <span class="or">OR</span>
                       </div>

        <!-- form of appointment -->
        <div class="row">
         <form method="post" action="#">
          <div class="form">
           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Full Name *" required="">
           </div>
           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email Address *" required="">
           </div>
           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Appointment Date *" required="">
           </div>
           <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number *" required="">
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
           <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Your Problem *" required=""></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
           <div class="captcha-container">
                                       <label>Are you human? </label><br>
                                       <img src="http://inspirythemesdemo.com/healthpress/wp-content/themes/healthpress-theme/captcha/captcha.php" alt="">
                                       <input type="text" class="captcha required" name="captcha" maxlength="5" title=" Please enter the code characters displayed in image!">
                                   </div>
           <input class="btn btn-primary send" type="submit" value="Send">
          </div>
         </form>
        </div>
        <!-- end of form -->
       </div><!-- end of appointment-->
         </div>
        </div> <!--  client-content  -->
       </div>
   </div> 
     </section> <!-- testimonial -->


  <section id="footer">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ul class="text-center contact">
             <li class="socials-icons">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share in Facebook" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li class="socials-icons">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share in Twitter" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li class="socials-icons">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share in Google +" class="google-plus"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li class="socials-icons">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share in Instagram" class="instagram"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li class="socials-icons">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Share in Pinterest" class="pinterest"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a>
       </li>
       <li class="socials-icons">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Connect with Skype" class="skype"><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
       </li>
           </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="copy-right-text text-center">
       © Copyright 2014, Your Website Link. Theme by <a href="https://themewagon.com/">ThemeWagon</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        new WOW().init();
  </script>

  <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#starting-slider").owlCarousel({
       autoPlay: 3000,
          navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
          slideSpeed : 700,
          paginationSpeed : 1000,
          singleItem:true
      });
   });
  </script>


  <script>
   $( function() {
      // init Isotope
      var $container = $('.isotope').isotope
      ({
        itemSelector: '.element-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
      });


      // bind filter button click
      $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() 
      {
        var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        // use filterFn if matches value
        $container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
     });
  
     // change is-checked class on buttons
      $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) 
      {
        var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
        $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() 
        {
           $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
           $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
        });
      });
     
   });
  </script>

 
</body></html>
```

Comment: Where is the code for the "read more"-button?

Comment: look in section class starting text….<section class="starting-text">

Comment: There's a whole bunch of stuff in here that's got little/nothing to do with your question.  Please check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to create a question that doesn't require people to wade through pages of stuff to get to the relevant pieces.  What did you want to have happen when someone clicks the "Read More" button?  It's not obvious what text you want to have appear, or where it should go

Comment: I simply want it to appear underneath the button and retract upon re click. I have posted my whole code because I simply cannot figure it out after sometime and I really am looking for help so I wanted to provide everything. I'm sorry. If you can help Id be very grateful

Comment: What text you need to show on clicking read more. specify it

Answer (score 0):

```
    function ibeGetDescription(desc) {
        if (desc == null || typeof desc == "undefined") {
            return "";
        }

        var text = new Array();

        var postDesc = "<span class='post-desc deluxTxt' style='display: none;'>" + desc + "</span>";

        text.push("<span class='dynamic-desc' style='text-align: justify;'>");

        text.push(postDesc);
        text.push("<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='ibeShowHideDescription(this);' class='greenTxt'>...More</a>");
        text.push("</span>");

        return text.join("");
    }

   function ibeShowHideDescription(obj) {
    var $this = $(obj);
    var $div = $(obj).closest(".dynamic-desc");
       var $postDesc = $div.find("span.post-desc");

    if ($postDesc.is(":visible")) {
        //$postDesc.slideUp("fast");
        $postDesc.css("display", "none");
        $preDesc.show();
        $this.html("...More");
    }

}
```

Change your class and use this function to show more section